# Send email with multiple Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a DE and my subscriber is present multiple times because he has multiple contracts (ContractID is the primary key).

When i send an email in a journey, the same subscriber will receive multiple emails.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: change the primary key to the subscriberkey? so they can't exist more than once?

Comment: No because ContractID it must be unique, and my subscriber can have more contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way you could control this is just by changing the settings of the journey.

In the `Contact Entry` you have three options:

- `No re-entry` - you probably don't want to use if you want to send to a customer more than once from the journey (think: welcome emails)
- `Re-entry anytime` - this option will allow your contact with more than one contract enter multiple times at the same time (for example: 3 contracts = 3 entries = 3 emails)
- `Re-entry only after exiting` - this option will deduplicate based on the contact (only the first row in the data extension will enter and the rest will get blocked)

From your description it sounds like you're using the second option and switching to the 3rd one should solve your problem.

This if of course if you want to leave the process as is and simply deduplicate, but maybe rethink if this process is good for customers with multiple contracts and adjust your data extension and email accordingly to represent all active contracts in one message.